# Skip Login Page Using access_token + Direct Access Grants with the browser flow

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm running into a problem and am not sure if there is a solution.

The current problem:
Website 1 (no-sso)
Website 2 (openid, managed by keycloak instance)

What I'm trying to do:
User access website 1 then is authenticated and authorized to website 2 using the browser flow and pass thru without seeing a keycloak login page.  It should be seamless (no keycloak login pages of any kind)

I'm able to generate an access_token using the rest api, but when I redirect to website 2 I get kicked back to the keycloak login page.  From the keycloak logs it looks at first the login is successful but after the webapp redirects then I'm presented with the keycloak login screen.

Is there an alternative browser flow that would allow me to do this?

-- rest api call that I'm using to get the access_token

```
        String uri = "https://keycloak02.localhost.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        String client_id="client_id";
        String grant_type="password";
        String client_secret="secret";
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("username", username);
        map.add("password", password);
        map.add("client_id", client_id);
        map.add("grant_type", grant_type);
        map.add("client_secret", client_secret);
        
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity= restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Object.class);
        Object object = responseEntity.getBody();
        HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
        
        if(!statusCode.equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            throw new Exception("Status code:" + statusCode + " uri:" + uri);
        }
        LinkedHashMap retMap = (LinkedHashMap) object;
        
        String token = StringUtils.trimString((String) retMap.get("access_token"));
```

Yes I understand that password grants are an anti-pattern.

Comment: I am a little confuse your question. #1 Do you want to skip login screen of Keycloak. It is fine but In Browser Flow, the Keycloak redirects the user to login options. It is conflict the definition. How to address it this situation.
And #2 the code seems get access token, It backend part of Sprint Boot OR front end?
Access token can call REST API for get/set something with Keycloak.  Do you want to skip Website 2 also with Website 1 token? I think SSO is answer for this solution.

Comment: I'm trying to use the access token to pass thru to website 2 (managed by keycloak) without having a login screen.  I found this, where a user is saying this is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565030/keycloak-login-by-skipping-the-login-page